# Algorithm for discretization

Tags: python, matlab, julia

A rectangle is divided into **N** elements and discretized only on the boundary.
Any clues on how to write an algorithm for getting co-ordinates (Xs,Ys,Xe,Ye) of an element.
where (Xs,Ys) are starting points of an element and (Xe,Ye) are ending points of that element.

Comment: I would recommend reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm

Comment: I would suggest to ask on https://math.stackexchange.com/ for this type of question.